# Is it possible to add custom images to google analytics dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I have a web site with some images. Once user clicks on an image I track this event with the image name as an action name. Names are not human readable but they could be converted to working image URLs.

Is there any way to create a dashboard with these images? I'd like to use native dimensions to visualise these events.

Custom widget could work here but I didn't find a way to create one. The only solution I can currently see is getting data with API and visualising it outside the google analytics UI.

Comment: Are you talking literally about displaying images, or do you mean the image names (or URLs, or something else text-based) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about literally displaying images. Ckickable URLs could be a workaround but I don't like it at all.

It's like the devices – they are presented with device thumbnails, and that's really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; you'd have to take the data and visualise it elsewhere. The native Google Analytics dashboarding tools are extremely limited, and not capable of what you're asking.